# perl system function not working if executed through cron

Tags: linux, perl, cron, system

**crontab**

```
* * * * * /temp/feroz/daemon/sync_ec2_s3.sh >> /temp/feroz/daemon/cronlog.txt 2>/temp/feroz/daemon/cronlog.error.txt
```

**cron script `/temp/feroz/daemon/sync_ec2_s3.sh`**

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /temp/feroz/daemon
/usr/local/bin/perl sync_ec2_s3.pl -vx
```

**`sync_ec2_s3.pl`**

```perl
my $cmd = "aws s3 cp $lockfile $s3_lockfile";
print "Step 1 $cmd \n";
my $rc = system($cmd);
print "SUCCESS <$rc> \n";
```

1. If `sync_ec2_s3.sh` is executed via cron as shown above, `system` command doesn't work, and I am getting a result of `-1` in `$rc`.
2. If script execute manually as `sh sync_ec2_s3.sh`, then `system` commands works fine.

Please help me to understand why it is not working through cron, and what I have to do to resolve

Comment: Check the environment. Cron usually runs in a limit env, you need to set the variables explicitly.

Comment: `system` returns `-1`, `$!` contains the error. It's virtually guaranteed to be `No such file or directory` or `Permission denied`

Comment: Tip: `system("aws", "s3", "cp", $lockfile, $s3_lockfile);` is a whole lot more safer than `system("aws s3 cp $lockfile $s3_lockfile");`, and it avoids the possibility of needlessly using a shell.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the `aws` command is in your path, or write the full path to the `aws` command.